# Запись Dataframe в MSSQL 2008 Кодировка

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

помогите разобраться:
Есть датафрейм который я хочу перенести в базу SQL

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
con = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://login:Pass@srv/trade_analiz_sql')
sale_TVC_total.to_sql('ABC_analiz', con, if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=1000)
```

Но при записи русские символы заменяются на знаки вопроса.
Параметр сортровки в SQL стоит SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.
В тестовую базу с параметром Cyrillic_General_CI_AS пишется без проблем, но в нужной мне базе данный параметр поменять нельзя.
Подскажите как быть.
Пробовал добавлять в подключении параметр кодировки

```
con = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://login:Pass@srv/trade_analiz_sql?charset=utf8')
```

пробовал разные кодировки, но результат тот же. Может не те кодировки пробовал? В сети ответа не нашел.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Какой тип данных у столбца таблицы в который попдает русский текст?

Comment: @MaxU dtype: object

Comment: @MaxU или тип данных столбца SQL?

Comment: тип данных столбца SQL таблицы

Comment: @MaxU Тип данных столбца sql : Text

Comment: @MaxU а можно ли как-то в соединении обозначить типы столбцов?

Comment: в соединении - нелья, он задается при создании конкретной таблицы. посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383000/pandas-to-sql-all-columns-as-nvarchar/34384664

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по тому что вы используете `if_exists='replace'` и данные попадают в таблицу, можно сделать предположение что у вас есть права на создание таблицы в SQL Server DB, т.к. при использовании `if_exists='replace'` таблица создается если таблицы с таким именем не существует или удаляется существующая и создается новая.

Попробуйте явно указать тип `NVARCHAR` для столбца с русским текстом:

```
from sqlalchemy.types import NVARCHAR

sale_TVC_total.to_sql('ABC_analiz', con, if_exists='replace', 
                      dtype={'column_name': NVARCHAR(<max_length>)}, 
                      index=False, chunksize=1000)
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, всё отлично заработало. Я две недели в сети искал что то похожее, но без  успешно. Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: @LesNick, всегда пожалуйста)